# Wiring the Select button to perform Javascript and HTML

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

I have a simple video player that streams .webm video files and a Gridview underneath which holds all of my files and Select buttons.

In my aspx page I have a javascript function `vidSwap(vidURL)` which is supposed to change the source of the streaming video. It works perfectly all in HTML when I use normal tables, but these gridview tables are still confusing for me.

Is there a clever way to wire the select button in gridview to perform a video swap on the player without reloading the page?

My XML File (Data):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
  <video name="2.webm" location="http://10.0.8.168/media/" />
  <video name="redcliff450.webm" location="http://10.0.8.168/media/" />
  <video name="sunflower.webm" location="http://10.0.8.168/media/" />
  <video name="Elephants_Dream.webm" location="http://10.0.8.168/media/" />
</root>
```

My ASP File:

```
%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="index.aspx.cs" Inherits="VideoStreaming.index" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Streaming Video</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function vidSwap(vidURL) {
            var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
            myVideo.src = vidURL;
            myVideo.load();
            myVideo.play();
        }
    </script>

    <script src="/build/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="/build/mediaelement-and-player.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/build/mediaelementplayer.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <table style="width:100%;">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <video width="640" height="360" id="Video1" src="http://10.0.8.168/media/2.webm" 
                    controls="controls" preload="none">
                    </video>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server" DataFile="~/App_Data/data.xml" />
                    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1" 
                        AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True" CellPadding="4" 
                        ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" 
                        onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:CommandField SelectText="Play" ShowSelectButton="True" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="name" 
                                SortExpression="name" />
                        </Columns>
                        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
                        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
                        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
                        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
                    </asp:GridView>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your code could explain better what you are trying to do

Comment: I've posted what I have so far. Basically it's just a video on a page with a table (Gridview) underneath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still want to use your JavaScript function you can try this

```
<Columns>
  <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
       <a href="#" onclick='vidSwap("<%# Eval("videoURL") %>")'>Play</a>
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
....
</Columns>
```

this is assuming there is `videoURL` or something related in your datasource. You can change it to whatever variable name/property that is providing the video URL from your XML

Comment: This would work if I could have the `videoURL` change depending on the value in my XML file. Is that possible?

Comment: For every item/row in your GridView, if the videoURL field is unique, it would change. This works with any underlying datasource. Yes.

Comment: Okay well this all works for me. I know the solution isn't _technically_ related to the Select feature of Gridview but it works nonetheless. Thanks a lot tcoder!

Answer (score 0):

You could do this pretty easily with some jQuery. Something like:

```
$('a.select-button-class').click(function() {
vidSwap($(this).attr('href'));
return false;
});
```

Comment: This assumes your select button is an <a> tag with the class of "select-button-class" and that the video url is the href of the <a> tag. You'll need to adjust it to match your markup.

Also, if you're not terribly familiar with jQuery, this single line should wire up all of the rows in your gridview dynamically.

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow. I just set the Gridview as having `ShowSelectButtons="True"`. When I hover over the link I get a `javascript:__doPostBack` link. Is there a way to manipulate that to run something like, say, `<a href="#"
    onClick="javascript:vidSwap('http://10.0.8.168/media/2.webm'); return false;">2.webm</a>`?

Comment: Can `OnClientClick` be attached to a Select link? I thought that was only for buttons.

Comment: I assumed you were using asp:LinkButton. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't sure how to comment on your question, so this is the only way I could figure this out...  Are you familiar with iFrames?  If you removed the video from the code and replaced that with an iframe, than changed the swap to load the iFrame, it wouldn't reload the page.

[w3Schools on iFrame](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)